# Error deploying to heroku: "Application Error shows in chrome"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When i try to deploy my test_blog to heroku. It shows "Appliction Error" in chrome.

So, i viewed heroku logs and it shows following result. Dont now what's making up the error!!

```
C:\Users\Nir\Desktop\my projects\blog>heroku logs
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739278+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/
ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739278+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/
ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `requir
e_relative'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739310+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739315+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739317+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:318:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'

2016-10-27T22:08:15.739319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:218:in `app'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739336+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `wrapped_app'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739335+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739339+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:282:in `start'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739339+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:79:in `start'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739340+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in se
rver'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739343+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739345+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739346+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command
!'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739351+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739352+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.739349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-27T22:08:15.921092+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-27T22:08:15.928895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-10-28T03:43:51.947800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2016-10-28T03:43:54.754771+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 33787 -e production`
2016-10-28T03:43:58.198367+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2016-10-28T03:43:58.198384+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.0.1 application starti
ng in production on http://0.0.0.0:33787
2016-10-28T03:43:58.198385+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more s
tartup options
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147728+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147813+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/
activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specificat
ion.rb:176:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but
 the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version i
s at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147845+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_sp
ecification.rb:173:in `spec'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147846+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `est
ablish_connection'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147880+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:125:in `block (2 level
s) in <class:Railtie>'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147882+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `insta
nce_eval'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147885+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execu
te_hook'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147886+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block
 in run_load_hooks'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147886+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'

2016-10-28T03:43:59.147888+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_l
oad_hooks'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147890+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:324:in `<module:ActiveRec
ord>'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147916+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147917+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/application
_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147918+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require
'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147921+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block i
n require'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147922+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_de
pendency'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147924+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require
'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147926+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block i
n require_or_load'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147951+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in
 load_interlock'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147952+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in
 `block in loading'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147955+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:117:i
n `exclusive'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in
 `loading'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147959+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_int
erlock'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147982+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require
_or_load'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147984+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:336:in `depend_
on'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147986+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require
_dependency'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147987+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_l
oad!'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147989+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.147993+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148009+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148011+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148013+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `each'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148014+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <modu
le:Finisher>'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148015+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148017+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148019+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initiali
zers'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148035+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/
ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148036+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/
ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_componen
t'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148037+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/
ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148039+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/
ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148040+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/
ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148042+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/
ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148044+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/
ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148062+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/
ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148064+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148066+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/
ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148068+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148070+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `requir
e_relative'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148074+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148091+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148092+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148095+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148096+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148100+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:318:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'

2016-10-28T03:43:59.148098+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148102+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:218:in `app'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148119+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148121+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `wrapped_app'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148123+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:282:in `start'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148124+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:79:in `start'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148125+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in se
rver'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148127+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148129+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148131+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command
!'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148148+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2
.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148149+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.148150+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-10-28T03:43:59.246397+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-28T03:43:59.281910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-10-28T05:36:16.867365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=murmuring-falls-27437.herokuapp.com request_id=62
ddb576-529b-4742-9768-47aea9e3c7e2 fwd="120.89.103.211" dyno= connect= service=
status=503 bytes=
2016-10-28T05:36:18.306748+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=murmuring-falls-27437.herokuapp.com re
quest_id=1d1711b1-b7a3-4885-9500-dfaac53806bd fwd="120.89.103.211" dyno= connect
= service= status=503 bytes=
```

This is the error shown in Chrome when i run my url:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile content? It looks as if you have not added `gem 'pg'`

Comment: i have added my pg gem as: group :production do gem 'pg' gem 'rails_12factor' end